# Header and Main Appearing On Same Line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, figure

could not find a similar question so thought I would ask here. I am a begginer and was just practicing/ fooling around experimenting with some stuff when I came across this issue. I am using semantic HTML tags header and main as good practice. I have a navbar in my header, and a picture in my main again using the semantic tag figure. Everything seems to work fine as can be seen in the first picture:

**Not Floated**

[image]

Once I try to float the list items to make a horizontal nav bar, the following happens:

**Floated**

[image]

Can someone enlighten me as to why? The UL/LIs are block level and so is the figure element, so I am confused as to why when I float the Lis that the image jumps up on the same level. I can remedy the issue by adding a line break in between the elements but that feels sloppy, I want to understand why this is happening? It seems that the bottom margin of the UL is overlapping with the top margin of the figure element, but either way I cannot understand how two block elements are jumping up beside each other as if they are inline?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the SO guidelines and how to ask questions on SO. Then edit your question with a minimal reproducable code snippet showing the issue. Last but not least specify what is wrong, what you already tried and how you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the floating in order to stop the float from affecting all coming elements. See here for details:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float_clear.asp

Answer (score 0):

Define the `<header>` and `<main>` elements as display block in CSS. Example:

```
header, main {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful?